# Blur Any Focused Field onSubmit | React Final Form

Tags: reactjs, react-final-form, final-form

This might be a bug, but I wanted to post here before I open a GitHub issue to see if the community at large has advice, or if someone can just call me out for doing it wrong.

I want to blur any focused field onSubmit. Simple.

According to the docs, the onSubmit function is passed `(values, form)` as arguments, and the `form` api includes ways to get all registered fields, and a method for *supposedly* bluring any field. Here's the code:

```
const onSubmit = async (values, form) => {
  const fieldsNames = form.getRegisteredFields();
  fieldsNames.forEach(name => form.blur(name));

  await sleep(300);
  window.alert(JSON.stringify(values, 0, 2));
};
```

I forked the basic example directly from FinalForms docs, and added those two lines to see if I could get their example to work, but it did not. To test, just type into the firstname field, and press your enter key. The field stays focused..

[CodeSandbox Demo Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-final-form-simple-example-formblur-not-working-487yw)

[Final Form: FormApi Docs](https://final-form.org/docs/final-form/types/FormApi#blur)

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`form.blur()` is how you tell Final Form that the field has been blurred (it marks the field's state as being blurred). It's more of a listener. To actually *imperatively* blur the field, you'll need a reference to the DOM element.

Something like [`getElementById('myField').blur()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_blur.asp).

Comment: I guess I misunderstood. Thanks for your time!